# i am new to spring i want to know what is meaning of this error?

Tags: java, spring

```
Sep 09, 2015 12:14:56 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [D:\CaveOfAman\SpringDemo\spring.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from file [D:\CaveOfAman\SpringDemo\spring.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: spring.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:79)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:67)
    at aman.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:14)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: spring.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.getInputStream(FileSystemResource.java:115)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330
```

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from file [D:\CaveOfAman\SpringDemo\spring.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: spring.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
`

Comment: Spring configuration file is not found to spring container with name spring.xml

Comment: Looks like you are telling your app to load its Spring config from [D:\CaveOfAman\SpringDemo\spring.xml] and your application is telling you that it it isn't there.